# Rails - RSpec/Capybara and AJAX: How to test an AJAX database update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rspec, capybara, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a checkbox on a page that sends an AJAX call to a method in a controller. A User checks this box to indicate that they have selected this Item, and the relationship is stored in a join table called UserItems.

How would I go about testing this? I currently have:

```
check "add-this-item-"+item.id.to_s
@user.user_item.item.should include(item)
```

The checkbox has a name that is "add-this-item-" plus its ID. Using pry-nav, I have verified that it is finding the checkbox and selecting it - however the test database does not update.

The checkbox does update the database when using the site locally.

I can't seem to figure this out. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to use a Capybara driver that can run Javascript, like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). The standard Capybara driver doesn't run Javascript, and thus wouldn't invoke click handlers or AJAX.